# Convert JSON string in array format into an array in java

Tags: android

I'm trying to take the following string that I got as a json object:

```
 [
    {
        "id": "picture1",
        "caption": "sample caption",
        "picname": "sample picture name"
      }
 ]
```

and turn it into a array so I can populate a list

I've tried turning it into a jsonarray by doing this:

```
JSONArray myjsonarray = myjson.toJSONArray(string_containing_json_above);
```

but that didn't seem to work.

==============

Here is full code with the working solution

```
myjson = new JSONObject(temp);
String String_that_should_be_array = myjson.getString("piclist");
JSONArray myjsonarray = new JSONArray(String_that_should_be_array);
For(int i = 0; i < myjsonarray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject tempJSONobj = myjsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    showToast(tempJSONobj.get("caption").toString());
}
```

temp is the json from the server

Comment: What is `myson`? And what is `temparray`? Have you looked at the [JavaDoc for JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.lang.String))? Take note of the constructor that accepts a string.

Comment: I edited the post to make more sense.  I'm sorry.  temparray is a string but i've renamed the variable in my code because it was a terrible variable name

Comment: Ok, so that clears some stuff up. But you didn't mention what 'myjson' is. But, see answer from @PareshMayani.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you get JSONArray so change

```
JSONArray myjsonarray = myjson.toJSONArray(temparray);
```

line as shown below

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readlocationFeed);
```

and after

```
 JSONArray jsonArray =  new JSONArray(readlocationFeed);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        explrObject.getString("caption");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Issue is here:**

```
JSONArray myjsonarray = myjson.toJSONArray(temparray);
```

**Solution:**

```
JSONArray myjsonarray = new JSONArray(myJSON);   
// myJSON is String
```

Now here you are having JSONArray, iterate over it and prepare `ArrayList` of whatever types of you want.

Comment: Sorry I can only mark one as correct but this is correct too.  Thank you Paresh Mayani!

Comment: I would upvote you but I don't have the reputation to upvote yet.  When I do I will.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

JSONArray isn't working because the JSON you provided is not an array.  You can read more about JSON syntax here: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

In the meantime, you could manually create your array by paring the JSON one string at a time.

```
JSONObject strings = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String array[] = new String[5];

if (jsonString.has("id"){
    array[0] = jsonString.getString("id");
}
if (jsonString.has("caption"){
    array[1] = jsonString.getString("caption");
}
...
```

etc.

Comment: Do you really prefer `String[]` over `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: No, I guess I just thought that since the question specified an "array" that that was what s/he wanted.